# Wordpress problem language

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, plugins

okay on our [testing server](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/idi/) the language works fine whetter your click it twice or more but when transffered onto the [clients server](http://idi2.tv/) bugs occured... to see the bug click on "FR" top left (it's now on French) once click on "EN" (it stays in french click it again and it gives you a page with no style saying page not found) . I've been over forums for the whole day and night looking for an answer... what seems to be causing it... it's the exact copy of the site from our test to live site.. server configuration??? what's missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your clients server, it's adding a directory to the theme path: "/wp-content/themes/idi/**fr**/style-FR.css"

This is likely a configuration error with the language settings on the live server.  I would start there.

The hackish way around this is to simply create that file path - but that's a complete last resort and I highly recommend against that approach.

Comment: when you say language settings??? do you mean installing a french locale for the server???

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear!

I mean that the language configuration options in Wordpress itself might be to be tweaked.  It looks to me like Wordpress thinks your French CSS file is in a place that it isn't (as evidenced by it looking for a 'fr' directory in your theme folder).

Comment: He's using qTranslate plugin; that's where the the language config options are going to be set.

Also, there's no WP version and little other metadata showing up in source, so he might he missing `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in header.php, which will include various qTranlsate code which might be breaking the plugin.

Comment: That's interesting....  Only thing I can think of is there's a databse glitch. Maybe reupload a copy of the local database backup to the production server?

Comment: did that like 4 times and still no luck..... do you think it would be that the language is not set on their server???

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the [qTranslate forums](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/)? Do you have something going on in .htaccess that is rewriting the URL, possibly a config from the plugin?